# Why does S"A start Hilchot Shabbat with the laws between a Jew and a gentile?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, shulchan-aruch

The Shulchan Aruch Hilchot Shabbat ([siman 243](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.243.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) starts with the laws between a jew and a gentile.

Why does it specifically starts there when it is more likely to discuss the importance of Shabbat at the beginning?

Comment: Cause the Tur organized it that way?

Answer (score 2):

Because Sim 243 deals with **procedures preceding Shabbos**, like:

> דין המשכיר שדה ומרחץ לעכו"ם ובו ב סעיפים:
>
> Laws of renting his property to a Gentile for Shabbos:
>
> One shouldn’t rent out his bathhouse to a non-Jew [before Shabbos] because the bathhouse is known to be his. The non-Jew will do work with it on Shabbat.

After he deals with that he continues with laws that define the relations with the Gentiles that continue into Shabbos.

Comment: Cf. Tosfos to Shabbos 2a, who uses this logic to explain why the Mishnayos begin with Hotza’ah, the last of the 39 Melachos.